# Hardness of a modified version of NTRU

Tags: lattice-crypto, hardness-assumptions, ntru

Let the modified [NTRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRU) be $h=f/g$  such that $f$ is not necessarily a short polynomial, is the NTRU problem  still hard in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding an answer is not hard, but answers will not be unique. Given $h$, pick your favourite short polynomial $g$ then compute $f=gh$ using multiplication mod $X^n-1$. As $f$ is unconstrained the resulting answer is a legitimate solution.

Comment: Thanks dear professor

Comment: I  don't know if I need to open another question or keep discussing here, 
another question how about distinguishing from uniform?

Comment: @DonFreecs I think the answers will be pretty uniform as well; fixing invertible $g$ and letting $h$ run over all possible values will give all values of $f$ and vice-versa.